# Building a class to execute a function (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

i'm completely new to python and I was just curious as to how i'd create a class named 'File' that would allow the following code to execute:

```
fname = input()
file = File()
if not file.count(fname):
    print("File ", fname, " not present")
else:
    for i in range(10):
        print(str(i) + " = " + "{0:5.2f}".format(file.get_count(i)) + "% ", end = ' ')
```

Comment: What would `File.count` and `File.get_count` do?  Are you looking for [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) style filename matching?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh The count function of the File class counts the number of occurrences of each digit and the get count returns the percentage of the occurrence of each digit

Answer (score 1):

We could create a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) subclass that accepts a file path, calculates the counts of each character, then provides a method that returns a percentage.

```
from collections import Counter

class File(Counter):
    def __init__(self, filename, **kwargs):
        with open(filename) as f:  # Caller can deal with FileNotFoundError
            super().__init__(f.read(), **kwargs)
        self.total = sum(self.values())
    def percentage(self, character):  # ranges from 0 to 1
        return self[character]/self.total

file = File("myfile.txt")  # 11223344556789
print(file.percent("1"))
# 0.14285714285714285
```